# What is the preferred way to represent data structures as strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

What is the preferred way to represent a data structure in C++? I would like to utilize strings, although if a better option is available, I would be willing to try that.

I've been creating a data structure for use in a larger program. The structure is supposed to represent something akin to a Python dictionary. I want to print the entire data structure as a string. Is there a standard way to do this in C++? The guidelines suggested using the `to_string()` function, however I'm not sure if that works as I want.

I'm using template classes, and am unsure that there is a one-off solution to handle whatever combination of Key's / Value's are thrown at the program.

I've been testing this so far with `char`'s.

```
// Table class
std::string toString()
  {
    std::string result = " { ";
    ListNode<Key, Value>* current = this->table;
    while(current != nullptr)
    {
      result += current->toString();
      current = current->next;
    }
    result += " } ";
    return result;
  }

// List Class
std::string toString()
  {
    std::string result = "";
    result += std::to_string(this->key);
    result += " : ";

    Node<Value>* current = this->list;

    while(current != nullptr) // changed to be current, not list
    {
      result += std::to_string(current->value);
      current = current->next;
    }

    return result; // added return
  }
```

This function works more like a builder for the particular string. It goes into the smaller data structures calling similar functions to get to the base.

I expected to have something like:

{ Key1 : value1, value2, value3, Key2: value1, Key3: value1, value2 }

I've just been getting { }

Comment: your second `toString` doesn't return anything, does it?

Comment: It depends what you need. If you only want to output the result, probably the most idiomatic way would be to overload `operator <<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&)`. If you need the string for some other things inside your program, `toString` looks pretty good.

Comment: The second toString did not have a return, however that didn't change the output.

Comment: The second toString is also an infinite loop

Comment: Why not just use a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: changed conditional; changes reflected in post. Output is still the same.

Comment: Also, `operator <<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&)` is good, but even better (if you want a general purpose string, and not a stream operator) `operator std::string()` should do the trick.

Comment: @Chipster I didn't know it existed, also I wanted to experiment with making data structures in C++. That's the same reason as why I didn't use something like ```std::vector``` either.

Comment: I also don't see the output of the comma.

Comment: Your `this->table` can be nullptr. Please provide a minimal working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Maybe you could serialize the object as JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Stringify-ing **Everything**

I think it'd be good for you to see an example of how this would work in practice. String-ification should be *fast*, *easy*, and *simple*. Unfortunately, it's not built in to the standard library.

**Nevertheless,** in a little over 100 lines of code, we can write code to stringify `std::map`, `std::tuple`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::set`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::list`, `std::vector`, `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, **and any combination thereof.** So, for example, you could have a tuple containing a vector of unordered_maps between ints and strings, among other misc. stuff:

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, std::string>> vect {
    {{10, "Hello"}, {20, "World"}},
    {{1, "1"}, {2, "2"}, {3, "3"}},
    {{1000, "thousand"}, {1000000, "million"}},
};

// If we can print this, we're GOLDEN
auto justTryAndPrintMe = std::tuple{10, 20, vect, 0.3f, short(3), 2398987239890ll};
```

Because of it's design, the interface we write will be **easy to extend to custom types** as well.

### Describing the interface

The interface has three parts.

- `to_string` overloads (this is provided by `std::to_string`)
- `append_to` overloads (we write these)
- One `stringify` function template, that calls `append_to`.

Let's look at the `stringify` function first:

```
namespace txt 
{
    template<class T>
    std::string stringify(T const& t) 
    {
        std::string s;
        append_to(s, t); 
        return s; 
    }
}
```

> Why use `append_to`? Appending to a string is very fast. When you're appending multiple times, `std::string` reserves more capacity than is actually needed, so any single append is unlikely to result in a new allocation because the string will have enough capacity to fit the object. This reduces calls to `new` and `delete`.

### Writing the interface.

`append_to` has a fallback, which uses `to_string`, along with a number of specializations for different containers. The specializations will be forward-declared, so that they're visible to each other.

#### Fallback.

This version the least specialized, and it's only enabled if there's no other way to append the object. We use SFINAE to check for the existence of a `to_string` method.

This `to_string` method can come from namespace std; it can be defined in the global namespace, or **`to_string` can even be defined in the same namespace as a user-defined type.** In the last case, the compiler finds it through ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup).

```
namespace txt {
    using std::to_string;

    // This nasty bit in the template declaration is the SFINAE
    template<class T, class = decltype(to_string(std::declval<T>()))>
    void append_to(std::string& s, T const& obj)
    {
        s += to_string(obj); 
    }
}
```

#### Special cases

There's to `to_string` function for `std::string` or cstrings, but it's simple to write efficent append functions for those.

```
// namespace txt

template<size_t N>
void append_to(std::string& s, char const(&str)[N]) {
    s.append(str, N - 1); 
}
void append_to(std::string& s, std::string const& s2) {
    s += s2; 
}
```

#### Forward-declarations of STL containers and types

It's a good idea to forward-declare these as doing so will allow them to call each other.

```
// namespace txt

template<class... T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::tuple<T...> const& t); 
template<class F, class S>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::pair<F, S> const& p); 
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::vector<T> const& v); 
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::set<T> const& v); 
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::list<T> const& v); 
template<class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::map<Key, Value> const& v); 
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::unordered_set<T> const& v); 
template<class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::unordered_map<Key, Value> const& v);
```

#### Handling ranges

This is pretty straight-forward. We'll write an `append_range` function that takes a begin and an end iterator, and we`ll use the`append_range`function to implement`append_to` for the STL containers.

```
// namespace txt

template<class It>
void append_range(std::string& s, It begin, It end) {
    if(begin == end) {
        s += "{}"; 
    } else {
        s += '{';
        append_to(s, *begin); 
        ++begin;
        for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
            s += ", "; 
            append_to(s, *begin); 
        }
        s += '}'; 
    }
}
```

#### Handling pairs and tuples

We can use `std::apply` (introduced in C++17) to expand the tuple into a parameter pack. Once we have that, we can use a fold expression to append each of the elements.

```
// namespace txt

template<class... T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::tuple<T...> const& t) 
{
    if constexpr(sizeof...(T) == 0) 
    {
        s += "{}"; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        // This is a lambda. We'll use it to append the tuple elements. 
        auto append_inputs = [&s](auto& first, auto&... rest) 
        {
            // Append the first one
            append_to(s, first); 
            // Append the rest, separated by commas
            ((s += ", ", append_to(s, rest)) , ...); 
        }; 

        s += '('; 
        std::apply(append_inputs, t); 
        s += ')'; 
    }
}
```

Appending a pair is pretty straight-forward as well:

```
// namespace txt

template<class F, class S>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::pair<F, S> const& p) 
{
    s += '(';
    append_to(s, p.first); 
    s += ", "; 
    append_to(s, p.second); 
    s += ')'; 
}
```

#### Handling STL containers

For all of these, we just call `append_range` on the beginning and ending iterators.

```
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::vector<T> const& v) {
    append_range(s, v.data(), v.data() + v.size()); 
}
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::set<T> const& v) {
    append_range(s, v.begin(), v.end()); 
}
template<class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::map<Key, Value> const& v) {
    append_range(s, v.begin(), v.end()); 
}
template<class T>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::unordered_set<T> const& v) {
    append_range(s, v.begin(), v.end()); 
}
template<class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, std::unordered_map<Key, Value> const& v) {
    append_range(s, v.begin(), v.end()); 
}
```

### Custom types: as easy as writing a function

This is really simple. We can just write an `append_to` method for the type. It can go after you include the header file containing `namespace txt`. ADL finds it automagically.

```
namespace foo {
    struct MyVec {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    }; 
    void append_to(std::string& s, MyVec v) {
        using txt::append_to; 

        s += '<'; 
        append_to(s, v.x);
        s += ", "; 
        append_to(s, v.y);
        s += ", ";  
        append_to(s, v.z); 
        s += '>'; 
    }
}
```

### [Click here to run the code](https://godbolt.org/z/r2MgVz)

### Using this code in your library

We can write an `append_to` function for `Table` pretty easily!

```
namespace YourNamespace {
// Here, I forward declare append_to for table 
// Forward-declaring it allows you to have tables of tables
template <class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, Table<Key, Value> const& table); 

template <class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, ListNode<Key, Value> const& node) 
{
    // We need to use the txt version so it's included in our overload set
    using txt::append_to; 

    append_to(s, node.key); 
    s += " : "; 
    append_to(s, node.value);  
}

template <class Key, class Value>
void append_to(std::string& s, Table<Key, Value> const& table) 
{
    using txt::append_to; 

    ListNode<Key, Value> const* current = table.table;
    if (current == nullptr) 
    {
        s += "{}";
    } 
    else 
    {
        s += "{ ";
        append_to(s, *current);
        current = current->next;
        for (; current != nullptr; current = current->next) {
            s += ", ";
            append_to(s, *current);
        }
        s += " }";
    }
}
} // namespace YourNamespace
```

Comment: I would use the most general forms of the standard container templates, including allocators, comparison functors, etc.  Except possibly requiring the first argument of `std::basic_string` to be `char`, since character set conversions are tricky.  So e.g. `template<class... StrArgs, class... SetArgs> void append_to(std::basic_string<char, StrArgs...>& s, std::set<SetArgs...> const& v);`

Comment: Nice, as far as the "one string to rule them all" theory applies. But if you have different kinds of string serializations... there is something missing. Like a double dispatch with a phony type or something. Think of "I need to serialize to a JSON string and to a TOML string and to some custom string".

Comment: I really appreciate the write-up! I'll look more into the append_to and to_string functions to see how I can implement them into my specific case. A lot of this is more advance than what I was expecting, or would be comfortable implementing right now. Thank you very much for such a thorough answer.

Comment: What I mentioned above could look a bit like this (using function overloading and phony types): ``template <typename>
struct type {};

template <typename SFmt, typename T>
std::string to_string(const T&,type<SFmt>);

template <typename SFmt, class T>
std::string& append_to( std::string& s, const T& value, type<SFmt> t)
{
    return s.append(to_string(value,t));
}``. Then all you need to do to support yet another string format is to declare ``class JSON`` and overload for ``type<JSON>``. And done.

Comment: @aschepler is right about using the most general forms of the standard container templates. It's not hard to modify the templates to do that, but it would make the code look an order of magnitude more ugly, so I opted to use the simpler forms.

Comment: @BitTickler If I were writing this as production code, I'd give `append_to` a final parameter that was a type representing formatting information. It'd specify details about what delimiters to use when printing lists; how to format numbers; whether and how to quote strings; and other details. Because static fields and functions can be accessed with the dot operator as though they were member functions, the object specifying the format could contain everything as constexpr static fields, so it shouldn't add any overhead.

Comment: @Carson I added some example code showing how you could use this in your library! If you have any questions or want more help, feel free to ask :)

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Looks very nice! Thank you very much!